# Searching for a way to do bitwise XOR on images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, xor

I am looking for a way to get the [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) of two images on the command line (or in another way that can be implemented in a program or script).

This should result in the same final picture as using the XOR blending mode in picture editors that support it (Paint.NET, Photoshop, etc)

As an example, say I have **Image A:**

[image: Image A (Seattle, from the Paint.NET documentation)]

and **Image B:**

[image: ImageB (an apple, from the paint.net documentation)]

then the result should look like this:

[image: Image C (XOR result of above images, from the Paint.NET documentation)]

The fun part of this is of course, that when you XOR image C with image B again, you will get an exact copy of image A.

Now, I have been looking all over the internet for a way to do this programmatically, but I have found nothing. Even ImageMagick does not support doing a bitwise XOR on images.

Does somebody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

ImageMagick can do it, although it's a bit convoluted. One way is:

```
convert img1 img2 -fx "(((255*u)&(255*(1-v)))|((255*(1-u))&(255*v)))/255" img_out
```

(`img1`,`img2`,`img_out` are the two input and single output file names respectively).

### Explanation

It's a bit ugly (I'm sure someone with more ImageMagick-fu than me could clean it up but it works like this:

1. `-fx "xxx"` basically says "perform the operation `xxx` on the image".
   In the expression above, `u` and `v` stand for the first and second input images respectively.
2. Now, `-fx` only has bitwise AND `&` and bitwise OR `|` in the way of bitwise operators.
   To reconstruct bitwise XOR, we need

   ```
   convert img1 img2 -fx "(u & NOT v) | (NOT u & v)" img_out
   ```
3. To get the `NOT` (there is a logical `NOT` but no bitwise `NOT`), we remember that `NOT x = 255-x` *if* `x` is 8-bit.
   So to get `NOT u` we can just do `255-u`, assuming image `u` is 8-bit.
   Hence, the ImageMagick command would be:

   ```
   convert img1.png img2.img -fx "((255-u)&v)|(u&(255-v))" image_xor.png
   ```
4. - The one problem here is that when ImageMagick does `fx` it normalises all the pixels in `u` and `v` in the range `[0,1]` instead of `[0,255]` as we expect, and doing bitwise on non-integers screws stuff up.
   - Hence, we have to multiply **all** occurrences of `u` and `v` in the above expression by 255 (so the bitwise operations work), and divide by 255 at the very end to get back in the range `[0,1]` that ImageMagick expects.

This gives us the original command,

```
convert img1 img2 -fx "(((255*u)&(255*(1-v)))|((255*(1-u))&(255*v)))/255" img_out
```

Voila!

Comment: That looks amazing ;D. There was a small error in your code tough (the second u should be a v). Fixed it. It does however take AGES to run... ^^'

Comment: ta, shame it takes so long to run though (I only tried it on those baby images you have). Writing some code would still be fastest, `-fx`  in imagemagick does have a reputation for being slower.

Comment: ImageMagick-7.0.11-Q8>magick.exe 1.png 2.png  -fx "u&(1-v)|(1-u)&v" img.png  (tested for 1 bit and 8 bit images)

Answer (score 27):

I found a need for `xor` on an image and the [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu) tool works for me.  G'MIC is incredibly powerful, as is Image Magick, but worth a look for solving some tough image processing problems.

```
gmic a.png b.png -blend xor -o result.png
```

G'MIC also works directly on the images posted above.

```
gmic https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws6e8.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoBIM.png -blend xor -o result.png
```

For help,

```
gmic -h -blend
```

[image]

Comment: It is very unfortunate that only one answer can be selected, as this gmic looks like a wonderful tool. (I selected the answer that I ended up using originally, which I should have but forgot to select two years ago). Thank you for this great answer!

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would do in Java:

Iterate over all the pixels of the two images at once. (for loop (x) inside a for loop (y)). Of course, use a `BufferedImage`. You can get the color of the pixel by doing:

```
int color = img.getRGB(x, y);
```

Do the same for the other image as well and perform the xor operation on the two colors. Store the resulting value in a new BufferedImage with the same dimensions as the two input images.

Here is some sample code:

```
public static BufferedImage xorEffect(BufferedImage imageA, BufferedImage imageB) {
    if (imageA.getWidth() != imageB.getWidth() ||
        imageA.getHeight() != imageB.getHeight())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimensions are not the same!");
    }
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(imageA.getWidth(),
                                          imageA.getHeight(),
                                          BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);

    for (int y = 0; y < imageA.getHeight(); ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageA.getWidth(); ++x) {
           int pixelA = imageA.getRGB(x, y);
           int pixelB = imageB.getRGB(x, y);
           int pixelXOR = pixelA ^ pixelB;
           img.setRGB(x, y, pixelXOR);
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

To load an image from a file use:

```
BufferedImage imageA = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/username/image.png"));
```

Comment: You might want to use BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, so that alpha does not cause differences.

Comment: I think it should be: int pixelXOR = pixelA ^ pixelB ^ 0xFF000000;

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do yourself, do it pixel by pixel.
If you want a library, I recommend `OpenCV`. This is very nice and open source library with huge operations supported in image processing area. It supports direct **XOR** using `^` operator.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that

A XOR B = (A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A AND B).

and that most of common image processing tools do have and, or and not operations the rest is quite easy :)

Working in Python, you could have a simple script performing the operation and even adding it as a plugin in the gimp ;)

Comment: BTW, I might have a  quick and (somehow) elegant implementation using Python and opencv. I could send it here if want need it ;)

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has all the logical operators on images and numpy images using bitwise_#  Where # can be xor, and, and, not ...  See [OpenCV - Intersection between two binary images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262312/opencv-intersection-between-two-binary-images)

Comment: I'd just want to XOR an image not against another image but against a binary key. I see OpenCV methods need two images...how could I get this? Thanks a lot  EDIT: Well, I've seen https://gmic.eu/reference/xor.html. I'll try it