# OpenCV - Intersection between two binary images

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

Let's say I have two binary images of the same size. How do I find the intersection between the two binary images? Only pixels of the same coordinate (location) on the two images that are white (gray - 255) will give white pixels on the output image (intersection).

Comment: You may use `&` and `|` operators, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961092/how-do-i-do-boolean-operation-on-mat-such-as-mat3-mat1-mat2

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [cvAnd](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-and) or [cv::bitwise_and](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-and) on the two images. The resulting image will be white only where both the input images are white.

EDIT: Here are the results of applying [cv::bitwise_and](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-and), [cv::bitwise_or](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-or) and [cv::bitwise_xor](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-xor) on binary images:

These are the two source images:

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

Here is the result of applying [cv::bitwise_and](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-and):

[image: imgAnd]

Here is the result of applying [cv::bitwise_or](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-or):

[image: imgOr]

Here is the result of applying [cv::bitwise_xor](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#bitwise-xor):

[image: imgXor]

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do this in python (with the images above):

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('black_top_right_triangle.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('black_bottom_right_triangle.png',0)

img_bwa = cv2.bitwise_and(img1,img2)
img_bwo = cv2.bitwise_or(img1,img2)
img_bwx = cv2.bitwise_xor(img1,img2)

cv2.imshow("Bitwise AND of Image 1 and 2", img_bwa)
cv2.imshow("Bitwise OR of Image 1 and 2", img_bwo)
cv2.imshow("Bitwise XOR of Image 1 and 2", img_bwx)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you need to install `OpenCV` for `Python`, save time by following [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361604/3491991) (installation has historically been quite a pain).