# how do I do boolean operation on mat, such as mat3 = mat1 & mat2?

Tags: opencv

I would like to do boolean operation on mat structure.
such as

"and/or/xor" ing two binary images

is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just do it !

```
Mat a,b;
Mat c = a & b;
```

Comment: Where can I find any documentation about it? I see some airthmetic operators, but their signatures differs.

Comment: Look here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html

Answer (score 4):

For the AND and OR operation, here is the syntax :

```
A | B /* OR operator */
A & B /* AND operator */
```

The XOR operator doesn't exists, but still, you can do it like this :

```
(A | B) & (A != B) /* Pseudo-XOR operator */
```

You may want to check the [Compare function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.6/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#void%20compare%28InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20cmpop%29) to do what you want

Answer (score 1):

All logical operations you have to base on the following functions.
First group of them, consists  of three, four parameters functions: bitwise_and(),  bitwise_or(), bitwise_xor().

For example:

```
C++: void bitwise_and(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst, InputArray mask=noArray())

Python: cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2[, dst[, mask]]) → dst
```

There is also bitwise_not(), which takes three parameters.

```
C++: void bitwise_not(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray mask=noArray())

Python: cv2.bitwise_not(src[, dst[, mask]]) → dst
```

Documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html