# Installing OpenCV for Python on Ubuntu, getting ImportError: No module named cv2.cv

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, importerror

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 system, on which I want to install OpenCV and use it with Python 2.x.

I installed OpenCV using the instructions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

The install seemed to run properly, no errors, the script ended with output

```
OpenCV 2.4.9 ready to be used
```

When I try to run the sample Python script, I get the following:

```
$ python opencv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opencv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv
```

I suspect I know why, I just don't know how to fix it. OpenCV installed to the current directory I was in when I ran the install script, it's a subdirectory of my home folder.

Others who get this import error after install seem to be having a path issue, and have luck adding this to their code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

or updating their PYTHONPATH with that same directory. I tried adding that code, it doesn't make a difference. I don't see any files in the "site-packages" directory. Should I have done the install in that directory? I imagine the installation instructions would have spelled that out. I suspect that my problem has to do with Python not finding the OpenCV install, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Please help me get a usable install of OpenCV as simply as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV - cannot find module cv2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2)

Comment: @krock I don't think this is a dup of that. I don't have the file cv2.so present in my site-packages directory like that user had. Also, I mentioned the two solutions that are given in that post, and neither worked for me here.

Comment: but you *can* import cv2 ? the old cv (or cv2.cv) module won't be there in upcoming opencv versions

Comment: @berak No, I can not import cv2 either.

Answer (score 109):

I think you don't have the `python-opencv` package.

I had the exact same problem and

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

solved the issue for me.

you can install opencv from the following link 
https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/
It works for me . 
apt-get install doesnt contain many packages of opencv

Comment: Why your answer should be different from the others?

Comment: The OP does have the package. Otherwise the ImportError would say, "no package named cv2".

Comment: Same problem, tried installing per the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

No luck. This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: That was so simple!  After agonizing over so many other incredibly complex "solutions", none of which worked, this did the trick.  Thanks!   :-)

Comment: sudo dnf install opencv-python for fedora.

Comment: It gives me `2.4.9.1`version. How can i get more latest versions?

Answer (score 30):

I also had this issue. Tried different things. But finally

```
conda install opencv
```

worked for me.

Comment: This will work assuming that your python is Anaconda.

Comment: Note `conda install opencv` dosen't work for windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 17):

If you want as simple as possible, install from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv libopencv-dev python-numpy python-dev
```

Comment: I had to cut out the `opencv-dev` part, but otherwise, this answer worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 11):

Use pip:

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

```
$ pip install SomePackage
  [...]
  Successfully installed SomePackage
```

And when you add a path to PYTHONPATH with sys, PYTHONPATH it's always restarted to default values when you close your Python shell. Check this thread:

> [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

First add openCV to your path (Quick guide):

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

after that, install the non-python packages pyopencv depends on:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-opencv
```

finally, use pip:

```
pip install pyopencv
```

Also, you can check this tutorial to install openCV in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

> http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: Which pip package should I use for OpenCV? There are many listed at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/, not clear which if any is official and/or current.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer with a short guide, please mark it as correct if was useful

Comment: This is not correct. The reason this error is shown is because the cv submodule is no longer present in recent versions.

Comment: I'm not talking about the reason of the error. I'm just giving a possible solution. It works for me, maybe could be useful for someone else @AndyHayden

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopencv (from versions: 2.0.wr1.0.1-demo, 2.0.wr1.0.1, 2.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.1, 2.1.0.wr1.0.2, 2.1.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.2.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyopencv

Answer (score 11):

Try `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` if you are using anaconda, it works!

Answer (score 9):

Find where the `cv2.so` is, for example `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, then add this into your `~/.bashrc` by doing:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and add

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

In the last line

And then remember to open another terminal, this can be work, and I have solve my problem. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Verify if cv2.so did compile, should be placed in:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Then export that path like this

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Same as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

My environment:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- Python 3.5

Since none of the previous answers worked for me, I downloaded OpenCV 3.0 from http://opencv.org/downloads.html and followed the [installation manual](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html). I used the following `cmake` command:

```
$ ~/Programs/opencv-3.0.0$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.5 -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5 -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.5m -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/ -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages ..
```

Each step of the tutorial is important. Particularly, don't forget to call `sudo make install`.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in the guide here:

http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

I resorted to compiling and installing from source. The process was very smooth, had I known, I would have started with that instead of trying to find a more simple way to install. Hopefully this information is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

Create a symbolic link to OpenCV. Eg:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py cv.py
```

Answer (score 3):

Its complete installation nightmare, but I'll give one more hope you can avoid building opencv from source:

**pip install opencv-contrib-python**

Answer (score 3):

You can build for source following [the official OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html). The crucial part is to set the `PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE`, `PYTHON_LIBRARY`, `PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH` and `PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS` parameters for `python3.6`. Here are all the steps:

1. Clone the repo

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
   ```
2. Create `build` directory

   ```
   cd ~/opencv
   mkdir build
   cd build
   ```
3. Configure

   ```
   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
         -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. \
         -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6 \
         -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6m \
         -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
         -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
         -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON \
         -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
         -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6 \
         -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6 \
         -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so \
         -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages .. \
         -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/
   ```
4. Build

   ```
   make -j8
   ```
5. Install libraries

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
6. Test

   ```
   python3
   import cv2
   ```

If you don't get the error "No module named cv2", then the installation was successful.

*Note: If you don't know the path to `numpy` for the `PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS` parameter, you can find it by executing `import numpy` and then `numpy.__file__` in a python3 shell.*

Answer (score 2):

If you really sure that you installed cv2 but it gives no module error. There is a solution for this. Probably you have `cv2.so` file in your directory

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

move this `cv2.so` file to

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

copy the file into site-packages directory

Answer (score 1):

if you are using pycharm platform it's very simple go into
*view=>tool windows==>python console*
after that you will see in the bottom the console with [1] :
type this `!pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:
`from cv2 import cv`

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the other options here, but I could not get `import cv2` working with Anaconda on Ubuntu. This is the only thing that helped:

`pip install opencv-python`

Comment: thank you. it working : pip3 install opencv-python.
//////
Testing: python3 /
import numpy /
import cv2

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to use 3.1.0 but after installing python says "cv2 module not found".

You likely have python but not python-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

then reinstall 3.1.0 and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me on Max OSX:
https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
```

I confirmed that you can import `cv2` in python using python2.7 and python3

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was due to the fact that I had not appropriately sym-linked the cv2.so file in the`~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` folder (the name of your virualenv may not be "cv", your version of python may not be 3.5--adjust accordingly).

If you go to the `~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` folder and ls, the cv2.so file should appear in light blue (Ubuntu 16.04) showing that it is linked. You can check the link location by typing: readlink cv2.so

If cv2.so appears in red (as mine did), rm the file and type: (for my install of python 3.5)

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so cv2.so
```

OR (if you have python 3.6)

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so cv2.so
```

If you are working in python 2.6 or python 2.7, you instead type:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

If the cv2.so or cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so files do not exist in your `/usr/local/lib/python***/dist-packages` location, check to see if they're in a `/usr/local/lib/python***/sites-packages` folder. If so, adjust the path accordingly. If not, something has gone wrong with your opencv installation.

This answer was inspired by information here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

try using sudo apt install python3-opencv

it will install the latest package of open cv.

Or you could try reinstalling the opencv package. It might have got corrupted during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall pandas, then install it again:

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

then

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv` for python3 or Ubuntu >= 20.04

Answer (score 0):

The error kept appearing to me after downloading openCV 5 times in a different ways, until i fond that all of them has downloaded in a random version of Python, all of them in `~/usr/local/lib/python3.10` and the latest version is `3.11` (which i expected that the terminal should be using it when i write 'python3').

that was the problem in my case, i just changed python version in vscode.