# cv2 import error with caffe python

Tags: python, opencv, import, caffe

I'm trying to write my own python layer in caffe, and when I try to compile it, I keep getting this import error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/username/caffe/layer_example.py", line 3, in <module>
import cv2
ImportError: /home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so:undefined symbol: _ZN2cv11arrowedLineERNS_3MatENS_6Point_IiEES3_RKNS_7Scalar_IdEEiiid
```

I've tried to find a solution online, and changed my ~/.bashrc to look like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/username/caffe/python:/home/username/anaconda2/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```

I'm still getting the import error though. Any ideas on what the possible solution might be?

EDIT: Fixed the issue!
I uninstalled opencv(2.4.10) on conda, and installed version 2.4.9:

```
conda install opencv=2.4.9
conda install numpy
```

That fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed the issue! I uninstalled opencv(2.4.10) on conda, and installed version 2.4.9:

```
conda install opencv=2.4.9
conda install numpy
```

That fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

could also be a solution.
Cuz caffe ubuntu installation guide install says you have to install

```
libopencv-dev
```

However, I observed that this package makes opencv only accessible to c++.
To use opencv with python I had to install `python-opencv`

I got this answer from [Installing OpenCV for Python on Ubuntu, getting ImportError: No module named cv2.cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215102/installing-opencv-for-python-on-ubuntu-getting-importerror-no-module-named-cv2)