# Compiling OpenCV: how to build the cv2.so module for python3.6?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been struggling with compiling OpenCV for a while. The system is Linux Ubuntu 16.10.

Unfortunately it seems that the only library binding / module for Python that is being compiled is the one for Python 2.7, that gets installed at this location:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
```

What I need instead is `cv2` for `python3.6`.
I have set up the link `/usr/bin/python` to point to `/usr/bin/python3.6` .

this is my `cmake` directive:

```
cmake \                                                                                   
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \                                                         
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \                                                  
-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \                                                      
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \                                                            
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \                                                       
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \                                                                
-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \                                                    
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/foobar/Downloads/opencv_contrib/modules \
..
```

any idea on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install opencv for Python 3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3)

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58915533/4137497

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the instructions here [Install opencv for Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3) on my Debian 8. All went well!
`import cv2` passes.

```
-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
-D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON \
-D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.4 \
```

I suggest the main key for your Cmake should be:

```
  -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6 \
```

Please check Cmake output for Python version for build.

Comment: Better to use cmake-gui to check all parameters, `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` for example

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with Google VM (ubuntu 14.04). Installing opencv on python3.4 version has been quite a task. I wanted opencv to be installed for python 3.4 but everytime it was getting installed on 2.7 version.

I will share the steps I followed so as to help others on it.

**Step 1** Follow all the steps as mentioned on openCv installation part till cmake. Link is given below:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Note: Install all the 3 packages mentioned at start. That optional one too..!! And dont forget to change the python version for which you are installing.

I did

sudo apt-get install *python3*-dev *python3*-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

Follow step 2 for cmake.

**Step 2** For installing opencv in specific version of python (ubuntu), you have to set the default (PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE) with the path to where your python is installed. You can find that out by using command *whereis python3.4 (or, your version)*. Mine was in /usr/bin/python3.4

Instead of cmake mentioned on the page, use this,

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.4 ..

Note: Dont forget to change your python version and path in PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE.

**Step 3** Follow the remaining steps as mentioned in the link till sudo make install

Hope it helps.