# "Conda" and "source activate" no longer work

Tags: python-2.7, environment-variables, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I had conda (Miniconda2) working in the past 3 months, along side Anaconda and many Python libraries. I use Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, suddenly after attempting to install openCV for python, neither `conda` nor `source activate` (for environments) are recognized by my terminal ...

message appear in terminal when calling "conda" (e.g. `conda --help`, `conda --version`, ...etc)

```
-bash: conda: command not found
```

message appear for `source activate envNAME`

```
-bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

when typing `$PATH`

```
-bash: /Users/USERNAME/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/USERNAME/miniconda2/bin:/Users/USERNAME/miniconda2/bin:/Users/USERNAME/miniconda2/bin: No such file or directory
```

its after [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215102/installing-opencv-for-python-on-ubuntu-getting-importerror-no-module-named-cv2) things stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `PATH` there is this line:

```
/Users/USERNAME/miniconda2/bin: No such file or directory
```

Have you done any follow up on this?

I had a similar issue but I am on linux. Reinstalling worked, but conda is a huge package so that's not a good way to do things when something is obviously broken.

In my case I had some other program overwriting some things on PATH!

Answer (score 0):

seemed to work after unistalling then installing Anaconda again