# Installing OpenCV in Python3.3

Tags: opencv, python-3.x

I'm trying to install OpenCV in python 3.3.2 and Ubuntu 12.04. I've followed this tutorial

[Install opencv for Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3)

but I can't seem to make it work. When I try to 'import cv2' it says there is no module with that name

Any help with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu, you can type command:
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
which will provide you compatible version of opencv to your python.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows. But then I copied cv.pyd from opencv/build/python/2.7/x86 instead of opencv/build/python/2.7/x64. It works if you do so. I hope it would be helpful.