# openCV module version with python 2.66

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use the cv2 module on a Centos 6.8 system running python 2.6.6 
The repository installed module gives me only "cv"

Does anyone know if the cv2 module is available on python 2.66? I'd rather not have to upgrade to python 2.7, since it risks all sorts of OS problems if I get it wrong!

Comment: OpenCV2.4 requires python 2.6 or higher, so it should be fine, however OpenCV3 requires python 2.7.

Comment: See my answer here. This works for python2.x also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943638/installing-opencv-in-python3-3/28535745#28535745

Comment: Thanks - the version of the module installed from repositories when I installed opencv-python was cv  (not cv2) - but I installed python2.7 and pip2.7 alongside python2.66 using "altinstall" and then was able to install the cv2 module