# How to use OpenCV in python 3.4 on windows 7 x64?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I have `windows 7 x64` and `python 3.4`. I try to use `cv2` module:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
```

[As I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3), there is no way to use `opencv 2` with `python 3.4`. Therefore, I downloaded [opencv 3 beta](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.0.0-beta/). But I don't understand how to use this stuff for my purpose. Folder `~\opencv\build\python\` contains `python 2.7 folder`, but there is not `python 3.4 folder.`

How to solve my task?

---

**Update (06.06.2015).**

OpenCV 3 has been released. You can directly download it from [official site](http://opencv.org/downloads.html).

Answer (score 1):

you need to build it from source using cmake. Follow the instructions of standard install procedure [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html), you will find OPENCVDIR/build/install/python/x64(or86)/3.4/cv.pyd. Copy this file and all the .dll files to the python site-packges dir, I was able to "import cv2"

Comment: Following your suggestion, I'm trying to build OpenCV 3.0.0-beta from source. However the tutorial is a bit outdated and I run into some problems. Could you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747195/building-opencv-3-0-0-beta-windows-python-3-4 ?