# Cannot find CV2 Module -- Cannot find PythonLibs on openCV build?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, cmake

I am trying to run a dumper script in Python 3.4.3. It is a tested script which works, but it fails for me saying that `ImportError: No Module named 'cv2'`

I think this might be due to the fact that openCV 3.0.0 didn't build the python bindings, but I am not sure. When I run cmake ./ in my build_binary directory it gives me these outputs (selected from a huge output):

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.9", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found suitable exact version "2.7.9")
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Found apache ant 1.9.3: /usr/bin/ant
```

and later on it gives:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.9)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/local/bin/python2.7
--
```

Any ideas why it cannot find my python libraries? Do we think that the problem even is that it didn't build the python portion?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3) has been dealt with in SO before. If, by any chance, you have checked this link before and it was not helpful in solving your problem I found some other useful links:

- [From the official OpenCV documentation;](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html#install-opencv-python-in-fedora)
- [From PyImageSearch website;](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/27/installing-opencv-3-0-for-both-python-2-7-and-python-3-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/)
- [Also deals with the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2)