# import opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to install opencv on Windows 7 64 bit and I'm using Python 3.5.1 32-bit.
I downloaded the .whl file for opencv as said in the answer in this question: [Install opencv for Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3) given by @user3731622. But when I try to do:

```
import cv2
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's *bumpy* in the error you get? `multiarray` is a part of `numpy`.
In this post: [ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import)
the solution is to install `numpy`. Do you have that installed?

Comment: you are right the autocorrector changed it. I'll edit my question. Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the `numpy` package? if not try
`pip install numpy` or follow the instructions here [link](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html)

Comment: No I haven't. I did now and everything is working. Thanks