# python not found installing opencv

Tags: python, opencv

opencv opencv_contrib cloned to my `~/code` path

Using pyenv with python 3.5.2 (installed with --with_framework) on mac

Executing:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$HOME/code/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/libpython3.5m.dylib \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/include/python3.5m \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python \
    -D PYTHON3_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE_HOME=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python3.5 \
    -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$HOME/pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
    -D PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

But the output remains:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /Users/me/.pyenv/shims/python2.7 (ver 2.7.13)
--
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       NO (Python3 wrappers can not be generated)
--     packages path:
--
--   Python (for build):            /Users/me/.pyenv/shims/python2.7
```

No more things to try from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3)

Comment: I would suggest you to follow this tutorial http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/