# How to link pre-installed OpenCV with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have OpenCV3 installed on my machine, and from Python2.7 I can import it with no problem,

`Import cv2`

But doing samething using Python3 would lead to *missing module error*,

I read some solutions that need to install OpenCV again, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3/21212023#21212023)

But I don't want to install OpenCV again from Scratch, so how can I just link Python3 with the installed OpenCV,

Thanks,

P.S

I installed openCV by following this page: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Comment: I installed latest version of opecv-python with just one command :`pip3 install opencv-python` on my windows machine. Maybe you should try it in your linux.

Comment: You have to rebuild it for python3 as the library needs to link with numpy3 also.

Comment: How can I build it for Python3? Thank you

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks you are right, I had to remove the build directory of opencv (release) and build again using cmake, make and install make,

Then I was able to use opencv from python3
I don't know if we need to write that as an answer, 
Appreciate it