# Error 'module' object has no attribute 'freetype'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, freetype, freetype2

I am using this code [Link](http://fireant.github.io/misc/2017/01/28/ttf-opencv.html) but it displays error of **module object has no attribute**  i tried to pip install freetype but nothing happened. Can anyone please guide me with this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np   
img = np.zeros((100, 300, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

ft = cv2.freetype.createFreeType2()
ft.loadFontData(fontFileName='Ubuntu-R.ttf',
                id=0)
ft.putText(img=img,
           text='Quick Fox',
           org=(15, 70),
           fontHeight=60,
           color=(255,  255, 255),
           thickness=-1,
           line_type=cv2.LINE_AA,
           bottomLeftOrigin=True)

cv2.imwrite('image.png', img)
```

Comment: Which version of opencv do you have installed?  Check `import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)`

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `freetype` module was added in opencv 3.2.0.

Comment: it is python 3.3.0

Comment: Not Python version. OpenCV version ? try the commands in @WarrenWeckesser 's comments.

Comment: sorry its opecv 3.3.0

Comment: Do you have a file called "cv2.py" in your working directory?  If so, change its name.

Comment: No cv2 is not in this file directory

Answer (score 2):

If cv2.freetype does not run in python you can still use freetype-py module.

I have written a wrapper around the PIL library api calls in opencv for python2/3 which can be used in the following way: (download from https://github.com/bunkahle/PILasOPENCV )

```
from __future__ import print_function
import PILasOPENCV as Image
import PILasOPENCV as ImageDraw
import PILasOPENCV as ImageFont
import cv2

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30)
print(font)
im = Image.new("RGB", (512, 512), "grey")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
text = "Some text in arial"
draw.text((100, 250), text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
print(ImageFont.getsize(text, font))
mask = ImageFont.getmask(text, font)
print(type(mask))
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
im.show()
im_numpy = im.getim()
print(type(im_numpy), im_numpy.shape, im_numpy.dtype)
```

It uses the freetype-py module in the background. PILasOPENCV is actually a project for migrating old PIL projects to OPENCV. Install with

```
setup.py install
```

or

```
pip install PILasOPENCV
```

More details and test can be found in github.

Comment: I get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonas/Projects/SudokuSolver/SudokuDetectorPy/genTestData2.py", line 16, in <module>
    draw.text((30, 70), text, font=font, fill=255)
  File "/Users/jonas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PILasOPENCV.py", line 2102, in text
    ink, fill = self._getink(fill)
  File "/Users/jonas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PILasOPENCV.py", line 1795, in _getink
    if not self.mode[0] in ("1", "L", "I", "F") and isinstance(ink, numbers.Number):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2):

I find `opencv-contrib-python-4.5.3.56` does not have `freetype`. I downgraded it to  version `4.4.0.46`, then it works.

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
```

Comment: this did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing `opencv-contrib`, you can install that with `pip install opencv-contrib-python`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. On Ubuntu 20.10, I did `sudo apt install python3-9` then I made sure that `import cv2` didn't work (not installed) then I did `python3.9 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python` and I could do `import cv2` but then `cv2.freetype` raises an `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'freetype'`. Also `opencv-contrib-python` is "Unofficial pre-built CPU-only OpenCV packages for Python" it's not an extension of OpenCV, in case someone has the same impression I did.

Comment: working fine for me. Python version:3.8.2 and cv2 version: 4.5.1

Comment: It didn't work for me. Python version: 3.10.13 and cv2 version: 4.8.0

Answer (score 0):

1. install [harfbuzz](https://harfbuzz.github.io/building.html) and freetype follow this [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/3.2.0/modules/freetype)
2. build opencv-contrib follow this [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3)
3. Put a symlink to the bindings in your local site-packages:

   ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so $HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/

Answer (score 0):

**[THIS IS A WINDOWS SPECIFIC GUIDE]**

I'm pretty late to this issue, but I hope this helps someone.

I've added links to an easy to follow guide at the bottom.

Here are the essential steps, you'd need to follow:

- Install CMake & Git (if you haven't already)
- In a folder git vcpkg (git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git)
- Install freetype and harfbuzz using vcpkg commandline

  - `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
  - `vcpkg install freetype:x64-windows`
  - `vcpkg install harfbuzz:x64-windows`
- Locate vcpkg.cmake file and note down its path
- Ensure C++ build tools are installed in Visual Studio 19
- Download and extract OpenCV & OpenCV contrib
- Create a empty dir called "build" inside the extracted OpenCV (not OpenCV-contrib)
- Modify CMakeLists.txt inside freetype module folder in opencv-contrib ([Link](https://gist.github.com/UnaNancyOwen/14c72a3f10a46d41c359ab6ea307a1d2#file-readme-md))
- Modify and run the following command:

  - `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" 
    -B D:\code\downloads\opencv-4.3.0\build 
    -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
    -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=yes 
    -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=D:\anaconda3\python.exe 
    -D OPENCV_SKIP_PYTHON_LOADER=ON 
    -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=D:\anaconda3\libs\python36.lib 
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=D:\code\downloads\opencv_contrib-4.3.0\modules 
    -D OPEN_CV_FORCE_PYTHON_LIBS=yes 
    -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\code\downloads\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`
- Use CMake GUI to make changes referenced at this link ([LINK](https://github.com/BabaGodPikin/Build-OpenCv-for-Python-with-Extra-Modules-Windows-10))
- Once necessary changes are made, click Configure and Generate.
- Building DEBUG & RELEASE versions using Visual Studio 19
- Test the installation by importing cv2.freetype from the environment you setup.

There's a comprehensive written guide over here:

- https://github.com/BabaGodPikin/Build-OpenCv-for-Python-with-Extra-Modules-Windows-10

Also, I've made a video inspired by the same tutorial, which can be found here:

- https://youtu.be/9YUDx3qzKwY

I would recommend watching the video and keeping this guide open on the side.

Cheers!