# Changing font family in OpenCV Python using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

### The above answer doesn't solve my problem.

I am using `cv2.putText()` to put text over a video.

This works as expected, but I am attempting to use a different font (*not available in OpenCV*).

I understand that OpenCV is limited to the `cv2.FONT_HERSHEY` fonts, so I am using PIL with OpenCV to achieve this.

I used this method with images and that experiment was successful. But I am failing when I try something similar on a video.

```
import cv2
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image

camera = cv2.VideoCapture('some_video.wmv')
while cv2.waitKey(30) < 0:
    rv, frame = camera.read()
    if rv:
        font = ImageFont.truetype("calibrii.ttf", 80)
        cv2.putText(frame, 'Hello World!', (600, 600), font, 2.8, 255)
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

I have the "calibrii.ttf" in the same directory and as I mentioned, this approach worked with images.

Here is the error:

```
cv2.putText(frame, 'Hello World!', (600, 600), font, 2.8, 255)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type FreeTypeFont)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load TrueType Font to OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv)

Comment: @Silencer I don't understand how you could think that this is a duplicate question. I get it that in the answer you're linking to is your own answer; but your answer is clearly for images not video. I explained in my question that I have the solution for images, but my question is how to apply a similar PIL solution to video. Do you have a solution to my question?

Comment: @zindarod Thanks for your comment. I literally just started learning OpenCV last week for the first time. That said, I know a video is sequence of images...haha. I just built some videos from images I created in OpenCV. It's a lot of fun, but I would like to use the already existing `cv2.putText` to put the text directly to the video, which works great!! Just, the HERSHEY font happens to be ugly. So, I am trying to avoid doing this the hard way i.e. image by image.

Comment: This may be useful... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697181/2836621

Answer (score 10):

You can use OpenCV's freetype module to do so, no need to use PIL.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((100, 300, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

ft = cv2.freetype.createFreeType2()
ft.loadFontData(fontFileName='Ubuntu-R.ttf',
                id=0)
ft.putText(img=img,
           text='Quick Fox',
           org=(15, 70),
           fontHeight=60,
           color=(255,  255, 255),
           thickness=-1,
           line_type=cv2.LINE_AA,
           bottomLeftOrigin=True)

cv2.imwrite('image.png', img)
```

The output of this screen is [here](http://fireant.github.io/misc/2017/01/28/ttf-opencv.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me with this. At first try, I am getting the `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'freetype'`. I am using `opencv 3.4.1` with `python 3.5.2`. Any suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: Probably need this `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: I created an new environment in Conda and installed `opencv-contrib-python`. I can `import cv2`, so it works, but I still get the same `AttributeError`. I am so excited about this module, I hope I can make it work. What could be the problem?

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726854/error-module-object-has-no-attribute-freetype, freetype does not work with Python