# OpenCV 3.4 building from source - CV2.so is not generated - Ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

This is not my first time to build opencv, however, I am not sure why the cv2.so is not generated. I use anaconda and here is my cmake line:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../output -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/b.safwat/anaconda2/envs/opencv3.4/bin/python WITH_FFMPEG=YES -enable-shared --disable-static -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..
```

The output does not show the numpy and I suspect this part:

```
--   Python (for build):  
     /home/<user>/anaconda2/envs/<myenv>/bin/python3
--     Pylint:                      
      /home/<user>/anaconda2/bin/pylint (ver: 1.6.4, checks: 113)
```

However, I have numpy installed and functioning properly.

Have anyone builded the latest version successfully? did they change the name of `cv2.so` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the exact solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212023/871418), and what exactly fixed my issue is by adding the following lines:

```
-D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=<path/to/desired/python/environment>/bin/python3.5
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS=<path/to/desired/python/environment>/include/python3.5m
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=<path/to/desired/python/environment>/bin/python3.5
-D PYTHON_LIBRARY=<path/to/desired/python/environment>libpython3.5m.so.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with generating Python 2.7 bindings. Found the solution by manually inspecting `opencv/CMakeLists.txt` file. I think transposing the variables for Python 3 may solve your issue.

### Symptom

Before you start building opencv, you can already tell whether you will get the python binding file `cv2.so` by examining the cmake command output at lines containing `To be built` or `Unavailable`. In my case I had:

```
Unavailable: cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv dnn_modern hdf java matlab ovis python2 python3 sfm viz
```

Notice how `python2` and `python3` show up as unavailable right away at the end.

### Fix (adapt python2 references for python3 if needed)

In `CMakeLists.txt` there's a line containing

```
BUILD_opencv_python2
```

Next to it are a bunch of lines that generate the output of the cmake command. They are helpful as they inform about which variables cmake expects. In particular, the references to numpy are mandatory to build the python bindings. From these lines, I learned that for opencv 3.4.1, I had to invoke cmake using:

```
-D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
-D PYTHON2_NUMPY_VERSION=1.12.1
```

I can see from your command that you use the deprecated `BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT` flag. For opencv 3.4 the flag names have changed, and according to the content of `CMakeLists.txt` the new variable name is:

```
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON
```

I also read in another SO comment that `cv2.so` won't be generated without the following flag (untested):

```
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
```

### TL;DR

Edits to your command:

- Remove: `-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON`
- Add: `-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=<path_to_numpy>/core/include -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_VERSION=<your_numpy_version>`

Comment: it still doesn't work, however, your note about that "Unavailable" saved me some time, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Check if python3-numpy is installed.If it is not installed, cv2.so will not be generated.